# How can i set 'r_fullprofile' access in linkedin developer apps?

Tags: linkedin-api

I have applied an API in my application to access linkedin recommendations that requires 'r_fullprofile' access.

Before linkdin api upgradation it works fine but now linkedIn apps not giving to set fullprofile access, thats why my application not working.

How can i set 'r_fullprofile' access?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Starting from [May 12, 2015](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes), Linkedin has limited the open APIs. 
Access to `r_fullprofile` requires that you apply for and are granted access to this information from LinkedIn.**

**WHAT YOU NEED TO DO :**

Apply for partner status with LinkedIn([Apply with Linkedin](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin)), explaining what your integration is and how it works. If it meets their criteria of "we feel that they’re providing value to members, developers and LinkedIn," then some or all of the restricted endpoints will remain open for that app, and ONLY that app.

**Member profile fields**

The following selection of profile fields are available to all LinkedIn developers:

1. Basic Profile Fields
2. Location Fields
3. Position Fields

**Member profile fields available to Apply with LinkedIn developers:**

The following selection of profile fields are only available to applications that have applied and been approved for the Apply with LinkedIn use case:

1. Full Profile Fields
2. Contact Info Fields
3. Company Fields
4. Publication Fields
5. Patent Fields
6. Language Fields
7. Skill Fields
8. Certification Fields
9. Course Fields
10. Education Fields
11. Volunteer Fields

**Check out this [linkedin page](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields) for more details on which fields are available to all the developers and which are not.**

Comment: Is there any field to get connections (mainly 1st connection) of a user?

Comment: I am afraid i am not aware of such field. Maybe, this API documentation link can help. https://developer.linkedin.com/docs