# How to get LinkedIn r_fullprofile access?

Tags: integration, linkedin-api

I am currently developing custom application(company specific) integrated with LinkedIn. I have received data with basic profile access to fetch and fill some fields on my application and now I need full profile permission. But as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895266/how-can-i-set-r-fullprofile-access-in-linkedin-developer-apps) it is not allowed anymore. I see that there are partner programs are there. So I have following questions with me.

1. How to get permission to access full profile data.
2. Do I need to contact them? If so how to contact them.
3. Is there any criterias to be completed ? if so if so criterias should I completed to be eligible.
4. Is it involve any price? if so how much ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Our company is a LinkedIn partner. It was not a short process. I was not involved with pricing (if there was any) so I can't give you much information there.

Comment: All this will be answered with 2) yes, you need to contact them, since they are the only instance that can actually answer it. And I kinda think they have contact information on the site... Also, please read the description on the linkedin tag.

Comment: @Marty :Could you tell me how long will take it roughly ?
 
 Thanks

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen : I opened a support ticket. Hopefully it will give a solution. I'll keep updating. 
 Thanks

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**QUESTION-1:**

For getting permission to access `r_fullprofile`,  you will have to apply to become a member of a relevant [Partner Program](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs).

Apply for partner status with LinkedIn, explaining what your integration is and how it works. If it meets the criteria of **"we feel that they’re providing value to members, developers and LinkedIn,"** then `r_fullprofile` endpoint will remain open for that app, and ONLY that app.

**QUESTION-2:**

Yes, i think you would need to contact them apart from filling the relevant Partner Program form. They should reply to you about the status of the submitted application in about 15 business days.

**QUESTION-3:**

There are multiple conditions on which Linkedin reviews an application. If your application does not satisfy any of the conditions, then Linkedin rejects your application. Make sure you are satisfying their eligibility criteria. I have listed the various criterias which must be satisfied in order to become member of a relevant Linkedin Partner Program.

**Eligibilty Criteria for Linkedin Partner Program:**

(Taken from this [linkedin page.](https://developer.linkedin.com/legal/api-terms-of-use))

You can use their APIs if:

1. You are developing an Application designed to help LinkedIn members be more productive and successful across the web; for example, by augmenting their profile and professional brand in an Application for publishing, discussing and sharing content with like-minded professionals.
2. Your Application is NOT expected to: have more than 250,000 lifetime members; make more than 500,000 daily calls to an API; make more than 500,000 lifetime people search calls to an API; or serve greater than 1 million daily plugin impressions.
3. Your Application DOES NOT rely on access to the APIs as a fundamental aspect of your business.
4. Your Application WILL NOT store or export any data from LinkedIn other than the LinkedIn Profile Data for the LinkedIn member that requested the data.  “Profile Data” means the name, photo, headline, contact information, experience, education, summary, and location of a LinkedIn member. Profile Data excludes connections, network updates, job listings, groups, companies, and any other content.
5. Your Application DOES NOT target current or potential paying customers of LinkedIn products or people engaging in activities related to those products—in other words, Applications used for hiring, marketing, or selling. Here are some examples (and exceptions) of what we mean by hiring, marketing and selling:

**Hiring:** Applications to find a job or fill a job, such as ones used to advertise, post, apply for, search for, recommend, refer, suggest, enhance listings for, or fill permanent jobs, contract positions, or volunteer opportunities, or for anything with a similar functionality (you can, however, use the APIs to develop an Application to let people apply for a job on your company’s career site, as long as it abides by the specification set forth here).

**Marketing:** Applications used by marketers or their customers for marketing campaigns, lead generation, campaign analysis, or for anything with similar functionality (you can, however, use the APIs to develop an Application to let companies manage their social media presence on LinkedIn, as long as it abides by Section 4.5(“Social Media Management: Company Profile and Statistics Data”)).

**Selling:** Applications used by sales or other outbound professionals for generating or finding prospects or leads, for sales intelligence or training, for relationship management, for systematic matching of individuals with their LinkedIn profiles, or for anything with similar functionality.

**QUESTION-4:**

I don't think there is any such price for using their APIs.

Taken from LinkedIn API usage [terms of use](https://developer.linkedin.com/legal/api-terms-of-use):

> If you agree to and follow these terms, you are free to use our APIs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am a third party developer and I distribute a Wordpress plugin that enables companies to create applications that can join one of those partners' program. However I am, myself, not eligible. Still, I need r_fullprofile access so I can develop, test and support my users. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: You can create a application in `developer.linkedin.com` and then use the `client_id` and `client_secret` for this application for testing. Go to `My Apps` section on the page and then create your application.

Comment: I think that's not the answer to the question Claude had. The steps Rahul profides, don't give access to r_fullprofile, so even developers with test applications will have to apply for additional access.

Comment: @RahulGupta Thanks a lot for your explanation! This information is totaly missing in the LinkedIn API documentation or at least I can't find it that and how request needs to be accessed. I applied for the Marketing Developer Program in the hope to get access to the r_basicprofile permission, but I got declined with the reason "you got declined" and it seems like I can't apply again... so what should I do now?

Answer (score 13):

This is the latest update as of now,

LinkedIn have **stopped taking new partner request** and has a update on their help portal.

***"This is currently unavailable. We’re improving our partner program application process. Updates will be posted on developer.linkedin.com. Thank you for your patience while we work on this."***

Hope they will come back soon.

Comment: Looks like it is available again now.

Comment: @TerryWindwalker how true is that?

Comment: @olawalejuwonm It has been some years, so I am not sure how true is that today. Even they open that apply portal again, it doesn't mean you can pass their application process.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to give you Latest Update on this.

As per **API version v2, you can't access r_fullprofile permission** to pull the full profile data.

- After contacting LinkedIn developer support got the below response-

> With the migration of API permissions from V1 to V2, we removed the ability to access full profile data. Unfortunately, r_fullprofile is not being granted at this time and there are no immediate plans to change the provisioning of the permission.

- Even, it is not available as paid/free service to anyone.

Please see documentation here for details on profile fields available with v2 apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api-v1-migration

Comment: Link is 404'ing

Comment: Linkedin docs updating at a rapid pace. changing every now and then