# linkedin /v2/me complains about permissions if I decorate response with 'positions'

Tags: linkedin-api

Issuing a request (with postman) to `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?fields=id,positions` returns:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "not enough permissions to access field $$* for GET /me",
    "status": 403
}
```

whereas the same request without query params gives me the user's basic profile, and whereas a request like `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?fields=id,positions:($*:(id,company,title))` returns:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "not enough permissions to access field id for GET /me",
    "status": 403
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

As an aside, I want `position` IDs, but the endpoint doesn't return them by default, contrary to what the docs say about them being required.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: @Muhwu no; i have moved on. LinkedIn is no help. They DO NOT "monitor" stackoverflow for questions with linkedin tags. I suspect that maybe you need fullprofile scope, but that apparently requires a partner account with linkedin. You wouldn't know that from reading the docs though.

Comment: This answer might help, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31524701/2725217

Comment: Though it's not clear from the documentation, LinkedIn API is private. You need to request authorisation from them: https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

Answer (score 0):

You are likely using the `r_liteprofile` OAuth scope. With this scope, you can only fetch the id, firstName, lastName, and profilePicture fields.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context

You cannot read the positions field, unless you have another scope. However, those scopes are only provided to approved partners to implement very narrowly targeted use cases.

Answer (score -2):

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,positions~)

Make sure you are authorised to use the api, using v2 key

Comment: note that I said "the same request without query params gives me the user's profile". My app has a v2 key.

Comment: I just created my app. I have exactly the same issue:
`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=%28id%2CfirstName%2ClastName%2Cpositions~%29&oauth2_access_token=oauthTokenGoesHere`
> Make sure you are authorised to use the api, using v2 key
@Ambarish What kind of authorization needed? I already have access token. What else do they need?

Comment: I authenticated via the v2 oauth flow and it gave me a valid token, but I get permission denied for `me`. Or do I have to enable v2 API from some settings for my entire app (I don't mean on my end but on linkedin's end)?