# Getting scopes to access LinkedIn’s Connections API

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I want to use LinkedIn’s Connections API which requires my app to have some scopes which are not available by default. I want to know what do I need to do in order to get the appropriate scopes or if I need to apply for partners program then which one should I apply for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get LinkedIn r\_fullprofile access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508923/how-to-get-linkedin-r-fullprofile-access)

Comment: This Question is not a duplicate. The post @Lusten quote was in 2015 and LinkedIn API's are updated since then. This question is relevant.