# Linkedin api v2 get skills : 'not enough permissions to access to GET / skills'

Tags: postman, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get skills from linkedin API.

- I used Postman
- I already got my token for the authorization

Here the get url  :

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/skills?ids={id1}&ids={id2}&ids={id3}&local_language=en&local.country=US&start=50
```

This is coming from the documentation :
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ref/v2/standardized-data/skills

I always get this answer:

```
   {
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /skills",
    "status": 403
   }
```

Did I missed something ?

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn closed part of its API for users. You can get basic things only. You need to subscribe to the partner program to get the full profile. Here are some links to help someone in need.

[How to get LinkedIn r_fullprofile access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508923/how-to-get-linkedin-r-fullprofile-access)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/full-profile?context=linkedin/consumer/context

https://legal.linkedin.com/api-terms-of-use