# How Can i fetch all details of a Linkedin User (Public Profile)

Tags: php, laravel, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch all the public details of a Linkedin user. but failed again and again. i am using Laravel framework. it is very easy to integrate socialite in Laravel and i also implement that. i authorized user and fetch its name email and profile image. but i also want to fetch its location ,Eduction Experience and other public stuff how can i do it. i also Attach my code with my post and image too for reference.  [what i am fetching right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvVxz.png)

**Socialite Package Used**

```
composer require laravel/socialite
```

**config/services.php**
i all ready set these details in .env file and also in config/servies.php file

```
'Linkedin' => [
    'client_id' => env('Linkedin_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('Linkedin_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => 'http://your-callback-url',
],
```

**My Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Socialite;
use Redirect;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
     public function redirectToLinkedin()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('linkedin')->redirect();
    }


    public function handleLinkedinCallback()
    {       
        //$scope = array('r_fullprofile');
        $data = Socialite::driver('linkedin')->user();

                // $user = Socialite::driver('linkedin')->user();
                // $create['name'] = $user->name;
                // $create['email'] = $user->email;
                // $create['linkedin_id'] = $user->id;

       echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data1);


    }   
}
```

**My View**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>


                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>


                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">


                                <a href="{{ url('auth/linkedin') }}" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <strong>Login With Linkedin</strong>
                                </a>


                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Login
                                </button>


                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My Routes**

```
Route::get('link', function () {
    return view('link');
});

Route::get('auth/linkedin', 'AuthController@redirectToLinkedin');
Route::get('auth/linkedin/callback', 'AuthController@handleLinkedinCallback');
```

Comment: What have you tried? The image you give doesn't help much. Whats the code you're running?

Comment: socialite is a package i used that package and fetch my linkedin username and email etc

Comment: any thing you want i will provide that information

Comment: Please do not post links to images of your code. Please post the code directly into your question.

Comment: This is my Code . There is another File which contains Secret Key And Public key of Linkedin. Which i Dont Show here .

Comment: This is the answer to that question. Check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508923/how-to-get-linkedin-r-fullprofile-access