# Retrieve FullProfile Permissions for Signed In with LinkedIn API V2

Tags: php, linkedin-api

We use LinkedIn API to signIn my web application, but currently, we are using V1 API, but now we want to upgrade V1 to V2, But after signIn somehow we can't access user full-profile fields.

We need to fullProfile fields of current member full profile.
So,Can you help me how to get full profiles fields?

we are following bellow API:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me

but in this API we get an only lite-profiles field:
`(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The LinkedIn API v2 is much more restrictive in what member data is returned. You have to make a request to LinkedIn to get access to a different scope (Basic or Full) which provides access to more member data. Although I'm not 100% sure I think you have to become a part of their [partner program](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs) to get higher access. This other stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508923/how-to-get-linkedin-r-fullprofile-access) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I will check with your suggestion.