# Where to apply for a permission to access the LinkedIn r_fullprofile?

Tags: linkedin-api

We lost access to some important user information with the upgrade to V2. We have read all the migration info and documentation posted. We would like to know where to apply for a permission to access the LinkedIn r_fullprofile?

PD: We have already sent an email to linkedin_support@cs.linkedin.com explaining some info about the company and how LinkedIn info is used:

"Our mobile app is a collection of mini social and professional networks that exist at physical locations. It is used in local venues, conferences and university classrooms. The ability gives our mutual users the ability to connect with people nearby with similar professional profiles. We use the vanity name to direct users to the public url page of other users. We strongly also encourage that our users signup using Linkedin and for those who don't have a Linkedin account to create one. We believe the integration add value to both of our companies."

Comment: PLease look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508923/how-to-get-linkedin-r-fullprofile-access