# How do I get the r_fullprofile permission for my Linked In OAuth 2.0 client application?

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Exactly how do I contact Linked In to get the `r_fullprofile` permission for my app? It's been a few days now and I can't find anything useful on the LinkedIn developers website about this. They've made the simplest of things really difficult and tedious to find.

For e.g. [this thread from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31524701/303685) reproduces from the LinkedIn documentation, the suggestion that we join their **Partner Program** in order to request the permission.

However, their [Partner Program](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs) page sucks. It tells me nothing I am looking for and reads like some marketing brochure from someone who doesn't really understand customers.

[image]

I just want to be able to sign my users in and get their full profile so as to protect myself against any malicious activity on my website. Getting as much data about the person you're going to do business with reduces the probability of a threat. That's all. I don't need nothing to do with marketing or talent or sales.

Clicking the **Consumer Solutions** link on the horizontal bar on the top of their website (as depicted in the previous picture) brings up their custom 404 page.

[image]

This is really discouraging. It makes want to not include the **Sign Up with Linked In** feature at all on [my website](https://sathyaish.net/?cmp=soq/56034191). I also think their lack of customer understanding is the reason many websites haven't implemented integration with Linked In, despite what their revenues say.

Besides that, their process is not conducive to creating a test application, because reading their literature leads me to believe that you have to cast in stone your domain name and the redirect urls when applying for the Partner Program. How can you submit those when you haven't written the code yet? You'll obviously want to submit test URLs of a test application and then want to change them later. Even if their process allows for that, nowhere is it mentioned so. It just feels like you're up against a wall.

Can someone just please tell me how to get the `r_fullprofile` permission? I'd first like to give that to my test application and then finally when I implement the feature for real on my website, then for my website for real?

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: This is harsh but, thank you for knowledge sharing!

Comment: @Divyesh_008 Yes, I agree with you. I was a bit harsh in my comments. I have deleted that comment. The gist of my comment (though with a sullen undertone) was that at the present moment, only customers that join their partner program, which is presently aimed at the enterprise, as I surmise from the answer given below, only those customers can get the full profile permission. And it makes sense because they've got a business to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily find how to get access to `r_fullprofile` because this is not available except is very limited circumstances, which are tied to those specific Enterprise partnership programs. Even in those cases, we don't always give this out. It depends on the specific use case.

Those partnerships are for mature/established companies, so the expectation is you wouldn't be changing of your site or domain name. (Although, you can add/edit/delete items app details, such as your `redirect_uri`.)

At this time, you can get `r_liteprofile` as part of the standard LinkedIn API offering. You can use to implement Sign In with LinkedIn on your site. I understand this is far less data than the full profile.

This probably not what you want to hear. However, given the evident frustration you had in finding the information on the developer site and the time you took to write this all up, I wanted to take the time to help clarify things for you and anyone else who comes across this thread. I'll also ask the team to see how we can improve the site and/or add this to the FAQ.

Comment: What abour r_basicprofile? We just need the linkedin profile URL when user signs in as we use it to claim pre-existent profiles. What enterprise product do I need to get access to r_basicprofile? Also, why not providing the linkedin PUBLIC url in the r_liteprofile? I mean you guys provide the email which is by far a more important data than the public URL

Comment: @AdamTrachtenberg how to get the r_basicprofile permission? as I want to access the vanityName which requires basicprofile scope.  Check the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/basic-profile?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Answer (score 0):

I have submit the request to LinkedIn support portal about this and I have got the below response from Dakota (LinkedIn Developer Support).

> **Unfortunately, the Vanity Name field is not available as a public API field.**

[image]