# How to add w_fullprofile scope to Linkedin app

Tags: linkedin-api

I have recently created a Linkedin App and would like to use the [edit profile API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1/compliance/profile-edit-api), which the w_fullprofile API scope. My application has access to the [r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile and w_member_social scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKdl4.png) by default. Does anyone know how I can obtain access to the w_fullprofile scope?

## What I have tried

[An older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508923/how-to-get-linkedin-r-fullprofile-access) about obtaining r_fullprofile permissions suggested applying to one of the partner programs. So far I cannot see how to apply for anything other than the Marketing Developer Platform, [which does not appear to provide access to the Full Profile APIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOfQI.png)