# How to get LinkedIn r_fullprofile access on Linkedin API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I need to get the *vanityName* for my application, but I'm getting *non-autorized* access with the **r_basicprofile**. The first and last name is working well.

I found some content about how to get the r_fullprofile access on Linkedin API on the own LinkedIn site, like the text below:

*To access any of the following full profile fields, your app must request the r_fullprofile member permission*
source: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/full-profile

Nevertheless, I can't find where and how to ask for this permission. I read in another post that LinkedIn has stopped taking new partner requests. But, I really don't know what is the correct information and how can I get the *vanityName*. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508923/how-to-get-linkedin-r-fullprofile-access

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig The links to the linkedin pages on the SO article you shared are broken.

Answer (score -1):

LinkedIn's answer on that page is very ambiguous. I think this is by design. They are protecting API access to r_fullprofile because of their own business interests, I would imagine.

I'd be surprised if someone doesn't sue them over this. It's supposed to be public information and is on the public internet.