# How to get r_fullprofile access from linkedin?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to get the r_fullprofile permission access from linkedin api. I want users to login using Linkedin Login. How do I get access to the r_fullprofile permission? I tried looking at [How to get LinkedIn r_fullprofile access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508923/how-to-get-linkedin-r-fullprofile-access) but the link referenced there is dead link.