# LinkedIn V2 API how to get connections and such

Tags: linkedin-api

I made an app and I am succesfully able to retrieve my own info (/v2/userinfo), but I would also like to retrieve a list of my connections.

My app says I have these permissions:

openid Use your name and photo
profile Use your name and photo
w_member_social Create, modify, and delete posts, comments, and reactions on your behalf
email Use the primary email address associated with your LinkedIn account

Does anyone know how I can get more access?

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/connections?q=viewer&start=0&count=50
```

Gives me the error:

**Not enough permissions to access: GET-viewer /connections**

What I want is:

1. Retrieve a list of connections
2. Be able to check what my connections posted i.e. is there a new post or now

Been going through the LinkedIn API documentation but I find it horrible, and I am unable to find what I am looking for.

Hope someone can help me out!

**EDIT:**

I have these permissions:

Share on LinkedIn
Advertising API
Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect

I got the /me endpoint working successfully, but most other endpoints are not working plus, I cannot figure out how to retrieve someone else their posts.

I want to retrieve posts made by other people.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you want `r_fullprofile` access or something similar, as far as I am aware of, this is now private API, and you can check out this response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31524701/2305199). But in essence you have to enter Partner Program.