# r_member_social and r_member_fullProfile missing from LinkedIn oAuth permissions

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I have registered an app with LinkedIn with users already onboarded and using the app. The app aims to help LinkedIn creators boost their productivity, eventually enhancing and growing their personal brand on LinkedIn. It aims to be a platform for convenient management for content and planning effectively.

For this, I have requested and achieved certain permissions from LinkedIn, but unable to get r_member_social and r_member_fullProfile anywhere.

As my objective via my application points in a positive direction both for creators and LinkedIn, I am requesting an approval of these two permissions, which I assure will be used with permission of members and only for them for their data.

This is a blocker right now for my application, as it fails to server it's full purpose without these permissions.

How can I get these permissions for my app?

#linkedin

I have tried requesting different products on LinkedIn, and got most of them, but I can't find these permissions on the platform.

#linkedin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get LinkedIn r\_fullprofile access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508923/how-to-get-linkedin-r-fullprofile-access)

Comment: @DarkBee no, it has no info about r_member_social

Comment: "*we removed the ability to access full profile data. Unfortunately, r_fullprofile is not being granted at this time and there are no immediate plans to change the provisioning of the permission.*"

Comment: r_fullProfile and r_member_social are different permissions. @DarkBee